# Problema ao Deletar Linha em Tabela SQL com Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com uma função, tentando deletar uma linha da minha tabela sql, porém nada tem acontecido.

`HTML`:

```
<span class="action"><a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete">Sim</a></span>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja excluir?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "deletar-aguardando.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
    });

    $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
</script>
```

No arquivo `deletar-aguardando.php` eu tenho:

```
include_once('conexao.php');

if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=($_POST['id']);
    $delete = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id='$id'";
    mysqli_query($con, $delete);
}
```

Meu arquivo `conexao.php` está funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta substibuir onde tem `var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');`

Por `var id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: não funcionou, continuou sem fazer nada no documento

Comment: no início do seu HTML, qual o valor de  $id ?

Comment: quando você fez este comentário você me fez encontrar o erro, rsrs. No inicio do html estava `<?php $id = $dados['idclientes']; ?>` onde `idclientes` é o nome da coluna da tabela e no arquivo `deletar-aguardando.php` eu coloquei o nome da coluna apenas como `id` e o certo era `idclientes`. Contudo obrigado, rsrs

Comment: Qualquer dúvida, é só mandar msg direta ou um comentário aqui.